# Is there a way to fix the installation of package 'afex' using rpy2 (in jupyter notebook)?

Tags: r, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, rpy2

The rpy2 importr seems to work well for importing all packages, except for 'afex'. See code below as well as the error. I am using jupyter notebook to run these commands on a mac, python version 3.7, and was wondering if anyone might have suggestions or a solution.

Thank you for your help.

Code:

```
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr

# import R's "base" package
base = importr('base')

# import R's "utils" package
utils = importr('utils')

# import R's "ggplot2" package
ggplot2 = importr('ggplot2')

# import library(afex)
afex = importr('afex')
```

Error:

> ```
> /anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface/__init__.py:145:
> ```
>
> RRuntimeWarning: Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package
>   called ‘afex’
>
> ```
>   warnings.warn(x, RRuntimeWarning)
> /anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface/__init__.py:145:
> ```
>
> RRuntimeWarning: In addition: 
>         warnings.warn(x, RRuntimeWarning)

Comment: The package just isn't installed in the library. So you need to install it. Maybe you installed it in a different R library and you thought it was installed here.

Comment: Thanks! It looks like I was able to install that package, but it is selectively not importable (unlike ggplot2)- see code below. Can you tell if I'm doing something wrong? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Here is the code, showing issue with afex:

packnames = ('ggplot2', 'afex')

# R vector of strings
from rpy2.robjects.vectors import StrVector


names_to_install = [pkg for pkg in packnames if not rpackages.isinstalled(pkg)]
if len(names_to_install) > 0:
    utils.install_packages(StrVector(names_to_install))


ggplot2 = rpackages.importr('ggplot2')
afex = rpackages.importr('afex')

Error:
/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface/__init__.py:145: RRuntimeWarning: Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘afex’
  warnings.warn(x, RRuntimeWarning)